# SQL Access - one search field for many subforms

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am a complete and total beginner so good explanations would help me in my studies.

I am building a form that searches a few different unrelated tables (partly related though). I have one form with a few subforms for each table (in this case dbo_FSDB and dbo_HI). I have a few fields where you can write the search criteria. I was hoping to be able to write for example 'Name' in the field and it would return the `SELECT` info of that name in all the subforms. I managed to make it work for one subform but am struggling to have it so that it searches in all of them.

Here is my code:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnName_Click()
 Dim SQL As String

 SQL = "SELECT dbo_FSDB.Name, dbo_FSDB.Number, dbo_FSDB.RCS, dbo_FSDB.Flag, dbo_FSDB.Type " _
    & "FROM dbo_FSDB " _
    & "WHERE Name LIKE '*" & Me.txtName & "*' " _

 Me.subInfo.Form.RecordSource = SQL
 Me.subInfo.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

The name of the subform I have working is 'subInfo' that is pulling the info from dbo_FSDB with the 'txtName' criteria. I would like 'txtName' to search the dbo_HI table with the subHI subform.

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to do .requery when assigning recordsources.

Comment: Why do I not have to do .requery?

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat what you've already done, but change the names

```vb
Private Sub btnName_Click()

    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT dbo_FSDB.Name, dbo_FSDB.Number, dbo_FSDB.RCS, dbo_FSDB.Flag, dbo_FSDB.Type " _
    & "FROM dbo_FSDB " _
    & "WHERE Name LIKE '*" & Me.txtName & "*' " _

    Me.subInfo.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subInfo.Form.Requery

    'now replace dbo_FSDB with dbo_HI in the sql statement
    'and change the field names where necessary.
    SQL = "SELECT dbo_FSDB.Name, dbo_FSDB.Number, dbo_FSDB.RCS, dbo_FSDB.Flag, dbo_FSDB.Type " _
    & "FROM dbo_FSDB " _
    & "WHERE Name LIKE '*" & Me.txtName & "*' " _

    'and replace subInfo with subHI.
    Me.subInfo.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.subInfo.Form.Requery
End Sub
```